# Как реализовать Flickable в Drawer?

Tags: qml

Работает ли в `Drawer`'е он вообще? Пробовал различными способами, но страница отказывается прокручиваться.

Один из вариантов примера

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0

Drawer {
id: drawer
width: Math.min(window.width, window.height) / 3 * 2
height:  window.height

Flickable {
    contentHeight: drawer.height
    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: 150
            Text {
                text: "OMG"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Имхо, должен работать, но могут быть и баги, так как компонент новый - Qt 5.7. Если выложишь код, будет проще подсказать.

Comment: добавил в тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0

Drawer {
    id: drawer
    width: Math.min(window.width, window.height) / 3 * 2
    height:  window.height

    Flickable {
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: idContentColumn.height
        Column {
            id: idContentColumn
            Repeater {
                model: 150
                Text {
                    text: "OMG"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like a boss. Большое спасибо.